# Number game Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, random

I am trying to make a number guessing game I have the basic part of it down but I am trying to manipulate it so that it initially stores a random number and from there the player keeps guessing till they get it right. If I should continue with the switch statement let me know or should i go back to the if/else statement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <style>
 </style>
  <body>
   <h1 id="prompt">Can you guess the number I am thinking of?</h1>
    <h2 id="prompt2"></h2>
     <input id="guess" type="text" value=""> <!--Box for the input-->
      <input type="button" value="guess" onclick="numberGuess();"><!--Button 
        that exacutes the code-->
  </body>
 <script>
  var randomNumber =Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)
  function numberGuess() {
  var number= randomNumber;
  var yourGuess=document.getElementById('guess');
    switch (guesspart) {
      case (yourGuess==randomNumber) :
        console.log('Correct');
        break;
        case (yourGuess!=randomNumber):
          console.log('Correct');
          break;
      default:
      console.log(number);

    }};
    /*if (yourGuess==randomNumber){
      document.getElementById('prompt').innerHTML ='You have guessed 
Correctly';
}
    else (yourGuess!=randomNumber)
      document.getElementById('prompt').innerHTML='Sorry the number was 
  '+randomNumber;
  };*/
   </script>

 </html>
```

Comment: Go back to if/then because switches don't work like that.

Comment: Well that's just great! Let us know when it's done.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### General Answer

For situations where there are two outcomes to the condition (i.e. a correct answer or an incorrect answer), you should use if/else.

> In order to for the comparison to work, you must set `yourGuess` as `document.getElementById('guess').value`. Right now you're comparing the DOM input to the correct answer (number), which will always fail.

#### Performance Implications

Using an If/else statement may be more performant, as it does not need to evaluate the condition of `yourGuess!=randomNumber`. This is true because we know that if they're not equal, they must be unequal.

Heres an example,

```
if (yourGuess==randomNumber) {
  console.log('Correct');
}
else {
  console.log('Incorrect');
}
```

Notice that we're only evaluating the condition of `yourGuess==randomNumber`, and not `yourGuess!=randomNumber` also.

Comment: Okay thank you but when I run the code it doesn't let me click submit again. I have tried putting the console.log to see what the correct answer is and when I type that in and click the button nothing happens.

Comment: See my note. You're saving `yourGuess` as the input element, and not its value.

Answer (score 0):

No need for that switch statement which could and should be done using a simple `if/else`.

You need to get the value from the element `document.getElementBydId('guess').value`

```js
var randomNumber =Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)
  function numberGuess() {
  var number= randomNumber;
  var yourGuess=parseInt(document.getElementById('guess').value);
  
  if(yourGuess === randomNumber) {
    console.log("Correct");
  } else {
    console.log("Incorrect");
  }
};
```

```html
<h1 id="prompt">Can you guess the number I am thinking of?</h1>
    <h2 id="prompt2"></h2>
     <input id="guess" type="text" value=""> <!--Box for the input-->
      <input type="button" value="guess" onclick="numberGuess();"><!--Button 
        that exacutes the code-->
```